# Nested fetch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch, es6-promise

I am trying to understand JavaScript, specifically fetch. I have the following code but it is not making sense to me because `console.log(responseObject)` prints data but `console.log(res)` prints undefined.

How is that possible? Why is `responseObject` not getting passed into `res`?

I do not want to mess around with `async/await` keyword as I find `.then` to be a lot cleaner.

```
  export const retrieveBasicUserData = (usernameFieldValue, setStateFunction) => {
  const responseObject = {
    data: null,
    error: null,
  };

  fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/test`)
    .then((response) => {
      response.json().then((data) => {
        responseObject.data = data;
        console.log(responseObject);
        return responseObject;
      });
    })
    .then((res) => console.log(res));
};
```

Comment: Your first `then` callback doesn't return anything so the chained `then` callback will receive nothing. Try adding `return` in front of `response.json()...`

Comment: Can't see why this might be classed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3478010.

Comment: @Phil Isn't return of a arrow function implicit. I mean it works here : fetch (URL).then(response => response.json()) .then (json=> console.log(json))

Comment: Return of an arrow function is implicit only if you omit curly braces {}.

Comment: @Roamer you might be right about the duplicate. One focusing on promise chaining would be more appropriate. Like this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/22539815/283366